# Is the notion of Archimedean Field First Order Axiomatizable?

Tags: logic, model-theory

An Archimedean Field is an ordered field $F$ of characteristic zero such that for all $0 \leq a \leq b \ $  in $F$ exists a natural $n$ such that $b \leq na $.

Let $ \ L = <=,+,. , \leq, 0,1>$ be a language of ordered Rings.

I'm trying to prove that the notion of Archimedean Field cannot be First Order Axiomatizable, that is, there isn't a set $\Sigma$ of sentences of $L$ such that $F$ is archimedean if and only if $F \vDash \Sigma$.

I know that there are ordered fields that are not archimedean, but I dont know if it will help.

Any hints?

Comment: See perhaps in MO [Is there a version of the Archimedean property which does not presuppose the Naturals?](//mathoverflow.net/q/15596)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would appeal to the compactness theorem.  Add to your supposed first order axiomatization the countable set $\exists c\ c \gt 1, \exists c\ c \gt 1+1, \exists c\ c \gt 1+1+1,\ldots$  Any finite subset is satisfied by the Archimedean field because you have finitely many of the new axioms and you just need to take $c$ large enough.  Then the whole set must have a model, but that model is non-Archimedean.  This model satisfies the original axiomatization, so it does not select only the Archimedean ordered fields.

Comment: Why did you say "your supposed finite axiomatization"? The set of sentences $\Sigma$ could be infinite. But I think that your argument works anyway. I add the new sentences to $\Sigma$ and then every subset has a Model, the real numbers, as you said. But the whole set cannot have a model.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote the answer I though your question had finitely axiomatizable.  My earlier update removed the reference to the reals because you might have some sentences in $\Sigma$ that excludes the reals.  We just need that $\Sigma$ has some model and has characteristic $0$ so we can add the new axioms and claim finite satisfiability.